# Preparing CSV file data for Scikit-Learn Using Pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a csv file without headers which I'm importing into python using pandas. The last column is the target class, while the rest of the columns are pixel values for images. How can I go ahead and split this dataset into a training set and a testing set using pandas (80/20)?

Also, once that is done how would I also split each of those sets so that I can define x (all columns except the last one), and y (the last column)?

I've imported my file using:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('example.csv', header=None, sep=',')
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the `sample` function in Pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd recommend using sklearn's [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# for older versions import from sklearn.cross_validation
# from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X, y = dataset.iloc[:, :-1], dataset.iloc[:, -1]
kwargs = dict(test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
choices = np.in1d(dataset.index, np.random.choice(dataset.index,int(0.8*len(dataset)),replace=False))
training = dataset[choices]
testing = dataset[np.invert(choices)]
```

Then, to pass it as x and y to Scikit-Learn:

```
scikit_func(x=training.iloc[:,0:-1], y=training.iloc[:,-1])
```

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Kartik. I imported `numpy as np` and defined `training` and `testing` as you describe above. I get the following error when defining `testing` though: `line 2765, in _evaluate_compare
    raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
`

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I forgot that `training` will have fewer rows than `dataset`, which caused the error. I have tested the code this time, and it should work. Again, I apologize.

Comment: Hmmm X is saying there are 0 columns instead of the correct amount which should be 1024 (`[3173 rows x 0 columns]`).

Comment: Use `.iloc` instead of `.ix`, like in the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Kartik that definitely fixed the problem. With that said I'll be going with @ayhan's answer because he did recommend using sklearn's cross validation function to split the data which is the best way in my opinion, and his use of .ix seems more appropriate. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

Sperating target class from the rest:

```
pixel_values = Dataset[df.columns[0:len(Dataset.axes[1])-1]]
target_class = Dataset[df.columns[len(Dataset.axes[1])-1:]]
```

Now to create test and training samples:

I would just use numpy's randn:

```
 mask = np.random.rand(len(pixel_values )) < 0.8
 train = pixel_values [mask]
 test = pixel_values [~msk]
```

Now you have traning and test samples in train and test with 80:20 ratio.

Comment: Thanks Randhawa. I'm not too sure what you're doing with the randn, and masks, but after fixing a few things I did manage to split my target class and my input features. I do feel like using sklearn's built in cross validation split is a much better choice though.

Comment: randn is generating random indexes between 0 and length of dataframe (no of rows)  and mask is used to contain retain 80% of these randomly generated indexes.